# RuntimeError when running a setuptools install command with custom options

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm using a custom install option in setup.py by subclasssing setuptools.Command but it throws an exception when the parent run function is called. Here's the setup.py code

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Command
import os, json, sys

class vboxcustom(Command):
    user_options = [
            ("disk-path=", "d", "Location where vbox disk files will be stored."),
            ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        self.disk_path = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        if self.disk_path is None:
            self.disk_path = os.path.expanduser("~/vbox")

    def run(self):
        settings_file = os.path.expanduser("~/.vbox")

        settings = {"disk_path": self.disk_path}

        f = open(settings_file, 'w')
        f.write(json.dumps(settings))

        super(vboxcustom, self).run()

setup(
        name="vbox",
        version="1.0",
        author="Ravi",
        author_email="email@email",
        python_requires=">=3",
        install_requires=["dnspython"],
        packages=["vboxhelper"],
        scripts=["scripts/vbox"],
        cmdclass={
            "install": vboxcustom,
            }
        )
```

The exception thrown is this:
`RuntimeError: abstract method -- subclass <class '__main__.vboxcustom'> must override` . It seems I have to override a method but what method(Im just guessing, the error is pretty non specific)

The stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 37, in <module>
    "install": vboxcustom,
  File "/home/ravi/work/virenvs/testvbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 25, in run
    super(vboxcustom, self).run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 176, in run
    % self.__class__)
RuntimeError: abstract method -- subclass <class '__main__.vboxcustom'> must override
```

I think I am not supposed to subclass from setuptools.Command to override the install command so I subclassed from setuptools.command.install.install and now I get a different error. The new exception thrown is this:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsGetoptError: invalid negative alias 'no-compile': option 'no-compile' not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve `user_options` from the class `install`:

```
class vboxcustom(install):
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ("disk-path=", "d", "Location where vbox disk files will be stored."),
    ]
```

Comment: @Ravi Does it help?

Comment: Yes that was the cause of the error. I am  stuck on a completely different error now, looking into it.

Comment: Fixed! Also had to call parent initialize_options and finalize_options